# How to store CAMediaTimingFunction controlPoints as a property?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I store these control points as a property so that I don't have to type them out multiple times in my class?

```
CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1)
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a property in Swift? If so, then why can't you do so in this case?

Comment: If it were as simple as `let controlPoints = (1, 1, 1, 1)` do you really think I'd be asking? I tried `let controlPoints: [Float] = [1,1,1,1]` which didn't work. Whatever I try doesn't plug into `CAMediaTimingFunction`. Trust me, I'm trying. Not a single book I've read ever demonstrated this type of example.

Comment: What about `let controlPoints = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1)`. In the future, please include what you actually tried in your question. Then people will have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: And thanks for the answer, I didn't think to do it that way. I was focused on the control points and didn't realize I could just make the entire thing a property.